# How to interpret stacktrace error reports

Tags: android

I released a new version of my app on the android store recently, and got an error report 2 days later in the android dashboard.  My new feature was to add more sound, which the stack trace seems to indicate as the cause.  Any idea what the below stacktrace means or how I can fix it?

```
DALVIK THREADS:
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2aacdf48 self=0xcdd0
  | sysTid=2611 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1876199472
  at android.media.SoundPool._load(Native Method)
  at android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:207)
  at maddy.toddlershapes.d.a((null):-1)
  at maddy.toddlershapes.ToddlerShapes.onCreate((null):-1)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x32d6fef8 self=0x225468
  | sysTid=2618 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=2246400
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x32d6fe48 self=0x224a70
  | sysTid=2617 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=2246232
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #2" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x32d580c0 self=0x130f18
  | sysTid=2616 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1230568
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder Thread #1" prio=5 tid=5 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x32d58000 self=0x131f48
  | sysTid=2615 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1253128
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x32d542a0 self=0x131cc8
  | sysTid=2614 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1249976
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x32d541e8 self=0x131158
  | sysTid=2613 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1263960
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x2ff58230 self=0x134818
  | sysTid=2612 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=unknown handle=1276096
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: The first indicated exception is `SoundPool.java:207` telling you that the exception was at the `SoundPool.java` class on `line 207`

The rest of the errors are nested errors (because if one thing fails, more dependant things fail after it)

I'd start looking into that class and the function on line 207 (probably `load()`) to see what is causing the issue.

Comment: load basically just calls the native int _load(String uri, int priority); - so I'm not sure what to make of that

Comment: `at android.media.SoundPool.load(SoundPool.java:207)`
so `load()` not _load(), dont ignore the `_` !

Comment: I looked at load() - it calls _load() - that load() method's job is just to call _load() - maybe I've missed what you are saying?

Comment: im not sure what the code is, so i cant possibly know what is causing the error, i was just trying to explain the stack trace to you :)

Comment: Thanks appreciate the effort :)...the load method is internal to the android api, so I'm not sure what it's doing either